# Call a method of an object with two different threads but same output

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-mvc

presume that i have a web application that needs to authenticate to another server and get a token to be able to call some methods.

and this token will be expired after 24 hour. so i need to refresh it.

based on some decisions, i want to refresh the token when i get a `403` response status.

I have a method like:

```java
public String authenticate() {
    // some authentication stuff
}
```

there is a possibility that two user try to use my service at same time while my token is expired.
this makes my application to call `authenticate()` method twice almost at same time with two different thread.

how can I make the second call in second thread to use the first call result in the first thread.

notice that i have `maven`(to getting suitable dependencies) and `spring framework` capability.

Comment: keep a copy of whatever result you want to re-use.

Comment: @aguest the problem is that i want to call method while no other thread is calling it. your solution makes two results because the first thread did not finished its work yet and the second thread cant find any result so it invokes the method again.

Comment: Why don't you just make the method `synchronized`? You can put a check for the last created token's expiration inside the method.

Comment: @gthanop this sounds like a good plan

Answer (score 0):

Here's the schematic for a solution; I don't feel obliged to write the code.

1. Single-thread the actual authentication
2. Save the result and save the time at which it completed
3. When you process the 'next' need for authentication:

   a.  If it's "not long" after the previous successful authentication, then reuse the previous result

   b.  otherwise start a new authentication

"Not long" might be as much as 23 hours for your case.

You might also need to clear the last-authentication result on session teardown.

Comment: imagine that while a thread is authenticating and still did not set any thing as last authentication, another thread seeks to authenticate and it do not find any last authentication, so it also start authenticating. in this case we may authenticate two time. which is not what we want. notice that it is possible that first thread start authenticating 1 nano second sooner than the next thread.